# How to insert the primary key as a paramter in SQL database table from code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables (Primary_Table and Secondary_table). Primary_Table contains primary key which is a foreign key for Secondary_table. Whenever I insert a new row into Primary_table I need to take its primary key and insert it into secondary_table. I am facing difficulties in taking primary key as a parameter. I need help on this.

string connString = "Database=MyServerDB;Server=ATLW732FV000169\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30";
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Primary_Table (TransactionType, Country) "VALUES (@transactionType, @country);"  +
            "INSERT INTO Secondary_table (BookingID,TripID) VALUES (@bookingID, @tripID);" , myConnection))
        {           
            // declaring Primary_Table paramteres
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactionType", "S");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", "US");

            // declaring Secondary_table parameters

            command.Parameters.Add("@bookingID", *****);  // Not sure how to insert bookingID (priamry key) into Secondary Table
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tripID", "tr");

            try
            {
                Int32 lines = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Lines affected " + lines);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: As is, it is impossible to give an answer since we can't tell the relation between your text and the actual code. Can you provide us some code?

Comment: i would create stored proc and use scope_Identity() to collect that and return instead of inline sql.

Answer (score 0):

Define a trigger [AFTER INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on Primary_Table that will take primary key of inserted data and insert it in to secondary_table.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

After your first insert -

```
DECLARE @var int

@var = select top 1 [pk] from table1 order by pk desc
```

This will get you the most recent record from table1 with @var being the pk, then simply...

```
insert into table2 ([fk]) values (@var)
```

This is easiest to do inside a stored procedure, which is considered best practice anyways (don't do inline SQL in your .NET code ever).

Answer (score 0):

you can insert in to primary and secondary table via one storedprocedure in sql :

declare @Primary_Id int

INSERT INTO Primary_Table (TransactionType, Country) VALUES (@transactionType, @country)
set @Primary_Id =@@identity

INSERT INTO Secondary_table (BookingID,TripID) VALUES (@bookingID, @Primary_Id)

and then in code :
command.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;